# Establishing a dependency in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a problem with establishing a dependency without redundancy in XSLT 1.0. I have a node type `a`, and a node type `b`. `a` is dependent on `b` - if I encounter an `a`, and there is not a `b` already present, I should insert one. Furthermore, I shouldn't change anything in any other situation.

**Input:**

```
<variables> 
    <var Value="a"/>
</variables>
```

**Output:**

```
<variables> 
    <var Value="a"/>
    <var Value="b"/>
</variables>
```

The difficulty I'm having is that I don't know how to search for `a` and `b` inside the same template. I can search for `a`, and replace it with `a` and `b`, but then I find myself with a redundancy when both were there in the first place. I can search for `a` or `b`, and replace the first instance of that with *a* and *b*, but then if I only have *b*, I'll be including *a* without wanting to. I don't know how to search for *a*, and then, if I find it, search for a peer-level node `b`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution employing the most fundamental XSLT design pattern. Extensive explanation is provided, too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "var[@Value='a' and not(../var[@Value='b'])]">

  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <var Value="b"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<variables>
    <var Value="a"/>
</variables>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<variables>
   <var Value="a"/>
   <var Value="b"/>
</variables>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".** Using and overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern.
2. **There is just one more template -- overriding the identity rule** for any `var` element the value of whose `Value` attribute is `"a"` that doesn't have a sibling `var` element with `Value` attribute with value `"b"`. This template copies its matching element and then creates a new `var` element as required.

Comment: isn't the "not(../var[@Value='v'])" selecting the same node and attribute and therefore will always be true?

think we should use `not(next-sibling::var[@Value='b'])". That should give us all nodes with an A, without a following B.

Comment: @Marvin-Smit: Thank you for finding this typo. Fixed.